# ansible: handlers are skipped when playbook runs with tags

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that I run tags "configure" and new configuration gets copied and I see the changed status in the playbook logs but finally handlers are skipped so my new configuration is not loaded

playbook log

```
TASK [my-server : Validate and copy config] ********
changed: [server101] => (item=/home/myitem.conf)

RUNNING HANDLER [my-server : reload service] **************
skipping: [server101]
```

here is my task

main.yml

```
- include: configure.yml
  become: true
  tags:
    - configure
```

handler

```
- name: reload service
  become: true
  supervisorctl:
    name: xxxx
    state: restarted
  listen: "reload service"
  when: xxx == "true"
```

task in configure.yml:

```
- name: Validate and copy config
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ config_dir }}"
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0640
    validate: "/xxx/xxx/tool check %s"
  with_fileglob:
    - /tmp/configs/*.config
  notify:
    - reload service
```

where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a role file?  Your handler should be in a handler file.

Comment: @kenlukas updated the question

Comment: Where is `xxx` being set?  The only way I can recreate your results is when xxx != "true".

Comment: xxx is in defaults set to true @kenlukas

Comment: I'd try running it without the `when: xxx == "true"` and see what happens.

Comment: Which version of ansible are you running?

Comment: ansible 2.8.4 @Zoredache

Comment: I tried adding the tag with which the role is tagged in the playbook to the handler task and I still have the same trouble as the original poster.
As with the original poster, I'm running with -t tag_name which correctly selects the
role from the playbook, but the role's handlers are "skipping".

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you obfuscated your task?  There are no tags on that either?  So that shouldn't be running.  But lets assuming it is running, and you had just removed the tags as part of your obfuscation.

I would be tempted to either add the 'configure' tag to your handlers, or perhaps the 'always' tag.

Comment: okay I updated the question. have a look